# powershell command wont run as it should from python script

Tags: python, powershell

im trying to run this powershell command:

```
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Lsports Tasks" -a
```

when im running it from powershell it works fine and i get the same ouptut from the python script, but when im running it from my python script nothing happens,im getting the same output that im getting from the powershell command but it dont work, here is my script:

```
import psutil
import os
os.system("""powershell -command ""Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Lsports Tasks\" -a""")
commands = []
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid','name']):
  process = proc.info 
  if process['name'] == 'svchost.exe':
     pid = process['pid']
     cmds = psutil.Process(pid=int(pid)).cmdline()
     cmd = ' '.join(cmds)
     commands.append(cmd)

i = 0
for c in commands:
  i+= 1
  task = os.system(f"""SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC ONSTART /RU system /TN "Lsports Tasks\Lsports Runner{i}" /TR "{c}""".format(i,c=c))
```

the output im getting from the command:

```
 CimJob1         CimJob          Running
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need admin shell?

Comment: what it means admin shell and how i can run it from my script? consider that from the script im kind of running it from cmd

Answer (score 0):

First you should give your program administrator privileges.And it works.(On windows)
like this:

```
import ctypes
import time
import sys
import os
import psutil


def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False


if is_admin():
    os.system("""powershell -command ""Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Lsports Tasks\" -a""")
    commands = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
        process = proc.info
        if process['name'] == 'svchost.exe':
            pid = process['pid']
            try:
                cmds = psutil.Process(pid=int(pid)).cmdline()
            except:
                pass
            cmd = ' '.join(cmds)
            commands.append(cmd)

i = 0
for c in commands:
    i += 1
    task = os.system(f"""SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC ONSTART /RU system /TN "Lsports Tasks\Lsports Runner{i}" /TR "{c}""".format(i, c=c))
else:
    if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
    else:
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u"runas", unicode(sys.executable), unicode(__file__), None, 1)
```

When I run this in admin shell,it is right,and some pid maybe miss.So add cache exc in here.

Comment: Hey johnny, still no success